# Calculating 2D array bounds in 1D storage

Tags: arrays, math

I have an array like below:

```
a b c d e
f g h i j
k l m n o
p q r s t
u v w x y
```

It's represented as a stream of characters (`abcdef...`) of which I know the position of each character (`01234...`). I need to find where the edges are in the array so I don't go out of bounds. Considering there's eight directions, I've come up with the below:

```
//n is numerical position, ie. n = row+(col*width)
//for the above 5x5 array, width = 5, height = 5
if n - width - 1 < 0 it's top-left corner
if n - width < 0 it's top edge
if n - width + 1 < 0 it's top-right corner
if (n - 1) % width = 0 it's left edge
if (n + 1) % width = 0 it's right edge
```

I'm not sure how to deduce bottom edges and bottom corners, however.

My best guess is:

```
if n + width - 1 < height*width it's bottom-left corner
if n + width < height*width it's bottom edge
if n + width + 1 < height*width it's bottom-right corner
```

Comment: Exactly what is `n`, what do you mean by numerical position? It's a 2D array so your position would be `n,m` as in `row,col`.

Comment: `n` represents `row+col*width`. `a = 0, b = 1, c = 2, ...`.

Comment: Is there a `height` value?

Comment: `height` and `width` are values I know, yes.

Comment: I've renamed your question as "edge detection" is actually something else completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deduce the exact position of your character using `n = x + y * width`: `x = n % width` and `y = n / width`. Now just test your respective edge cases:

- `x == 0` (left)
- `x == width - 1` (right)
- `y == 0` (top)
- `y == height - 1` (bottom)

Answer (score 1):

The bottom row would be from:

```
( height*width - width <"u"> ) [to] ( height*width - 1 <"y"> )
```

All the items between would be the bottom row, while the edge of those `height*width - width` would be the bottom-left corner and `height*width - 1` the bottom right corner.